# Silverlight 4 Datagrid and ContextMenu Binding to a Textbox?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, contextmenu

I'm simply trying to add a right click context menu for cut/copy/paste to a datagrid so you can right-click on each cell.

I got the menu showing up fine, the trouble is trying to execute the command correctly

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BasicTitleEditCellTemplate">
     <local:DataContextPropagationGrid>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White"  />
          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
             <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                 <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Cut" Click="Test_Method" />
                 <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Copy" />
                 <toolkit:Separator/>
                 <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
             </toolkit:ContextMenu>
         </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
      </local:DataContextPropagationGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now the problem I'm having a hard time figuring out, is when the user clicks one of the context menu items, How do I get the text from the textbox they're clicking on?  Or the selected text of it rather?

In WPF it always seemed like there were ways you could get the control that the context menu is bound to, I can't figure out anyway in Silverlight to get a reference to that textbox.

How is this commonly done?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information like are you using MVVM or what?

But it looks pretty simple

```
  <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Cut" CommandParameter="{Binding YourItem}" Command="{Binding YourClickCommand}"/>
```